# Is there a way to prevent Android Studio or Intellij IDEA from downloading older version of gradle over and over?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I have the latest version of gradle (7.4) installed on my machine, every time I open a new project on Android Studio or Intellij to write Kotlin codes, it starts downloading old versions of gradle, is there a way to stop it or to run AS/IDEA offline ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the `distributionUrl` property in the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file to point to a local file. So download a single copy of the necessary Gradle version from https://services.gradle.org/distributions/. Then before you open a project in the IDE, edit its `gradle-wrapper.properties` file to point to this local copy. It will copy the local file instead of downloading it.

For example, change

```properties
distributionUrl=“http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-bin.zip”
```

to

```properties
distributionUrl=file\:///C:/gradle-7.4-all.zip
```

I found a post about doing this [here](http://gurusurend.com/gradle-zip-in-local-system-using-gradle-wrapper/).

Comment: I may have misread your question. My answer is only applicable to opening existing projects that are using older Gradle versions.

Comment: It works even with new projects, you just have to create the new project then cancel the gradle download and then modify the file, then reload hard disk, then sync gradle.